# AVD emulator not launching in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to launch the AVD emulator in Eclipse and nothing happens.
The console reads:

```
[2012-09-11 17:06:02 - SecondAPP] Android Launch!
[2012-09-11 17:06:02 - SecondAPP] adb is running normally.
[2012-09-11 17:06:02 - SecondAPP] Performing ie.mf.secondapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-09-11 17:06:02 - SecondAPP] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MyAVD'
[2012-09-11 17:06:02 - SecondAPP] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MyAVD'
```

Everything seems to run normally, then it just stops at this point.

I have no idea what the problem is, I've tried completely to uninstall everything and reinstall everything and no change.

Comment: Have you tried looking at logcat? Pay attention to warnings (the orange lines)

Comment: what is your android target version  and what is your avd's android version

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, in my case the emulator won't start because opengles failure, so i add `-gpu on` in `Additional Emulator Command Line Options`([Emulator - accel graphics](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-graphics)), and then the emulator work normally.